# cakephp email attachment size

Tags: email, cakephp, email-attachments

I am using cakephp 2.3. I am sending email using the following code, which is working fine with 2MB or evern 3MB of file size. But when there is file with 7MB of size then it gives internal error and do not show any specific error.

I have try to solve it with increasing the memory size but it did not works

Can any one help me regarding this to fix it.

```
$file_name= APP."webroot/$file_name";
$email = new CakeEmail();
$email->from(array('info@example.com' => 'Example'));
$email->to($email_);//$email
$email->subject('an example - '.$form_name);                
$email->emailFormat('html');
$body="Body of email";
$email->attachments(array(
    "$form_name.pdf" => array(
    'file' => $file_name,
    'mimetype' => 'application/pdf',
    'contentId' => 'an-id'
    )
));
$email->send($body);
```

Comment: try calling   flush();

Comment: Maybe your memory limit is too low? What is the current limit?

Comment: Its a cloud server and I set the memory limit 500MB with ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');

Answer (score 1):

Internal error seems like its timing out. Try turn debug on and see if there is more detailed errors available.

7MB is quite big for the user to sit around waiting to send, this should be done in a offline process with some type of message queue.

Comment: Also, check the log files, error 500 messages should probably add something to the (apache) log file

Comment: Yes this make sense. I will try and will let you know.

Comment: I got this error in appache log `sendmail: fatal: apache(48)`